# Creating a matrix to SCALE around an arbitrary axis?

Tags: math, matrix, matrix-multiplication, scaling

I know how to create a rotation matrix around an arbitrary axis.  But I'm looking to SCALE around an arbitrary axis.  The goal is to produce a ray-trace where the ray has thickness.  Ultimately what I want to do is specify ray's start/end point, and a thickness.

Then the algorithm would scale all candidate faces around the ray's axis, and then I can do a simple DoesLineIntersectTriangle test.

However, online I can find dozens of examples of creating a rotation matrix around an axis... but I can't find even a single example of SCALING around an axis.

The only way I can think of would be to rotate the matrix so the ray is, say, aligned to the Z axis, then I can scale everything else's xy axis.  But that seems like a hacky way of doing it.  Is there a known algo for scaling around an axis?

(Preferably in C++, though I can convert from other languages)

So, this appears to be a NON-working concept:

```
Matrix& Matrix::ScaleAroundAxis3D(Vector theAxis, float theScale)
{
    Matrix aMat;
    aMat.RotateFromTo(theAxis,Vector(0,0,-1));
    aMat.Scale(theScale,theScale,1.0f);
    aMat.Multiply(&BuildRotateFromToMatrix(Vector(0,0,-1),theAxis));
    return Multiply(&aMat);
}
```

Producing this result when I specify the axis as Vector(.707,0,.707):
[image: Picture of results]

Red is the original quad, yellow line is the axis, green is the quad transformed via the function above.  But shouldn't the green result lie in the same plane as the red quads, only appropriately shrunk around the axis?

Comment: You don't scale a light ray like that, they don't have volume. Instead, you'd cast a lot of parallel light rays spread out over the area of and perpendicular to a disc. POV-Ray is open source and has cylindrical light sources. Maybe there's something in its code that would tell you how to compute those. See [Tutorial: visible (laser) light beams with povray](https://guido.vonrudorff.de/2013/tutorial-visible-laser-light-beams-with-povray/), [3.4.4.1.3 Cylindrical Lights](https://www.povray.org/documentation/3.7.0/r3_4.html#r3_4_4_1_3), and [the povray repo](https://github.com/POV-Ray/povray).

Comment: I'm not trying to cast lights, though, I'm trying to do some quick picking.  It's actually to say "is there a passage big enough for a sphere of radius n to pass through" in a world mesh.

Comment: Well-- not quite.  Because the final use of this is to say "is the cylinder COMPLETELY in the mesh."  Like a thick ray.  I can do "is cylinder touching" but what I want to get is "is cylinder's entire radius going through the mesh."

Comment: You need a way to differentiate between going through a hole in the mesh and going around the mesh. (These are kind of the same thing otherwise.) Geometrically, you'd squash the mesh to plane that's perpendicular to the ray. The outer edges can form a polygon. If the point where the ray intersects the plane is inside the polygon, and the cylinder test indicates the cylinder did not intersect the mesh, you've found a hole where a ball could pass through in a straight line.

Comment: "Geometrically, you'd squash the mesh to plane that's perpendicular to the ray" Yes... that's exactly what I need-- except that would be an infinite cylinder, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yeah. The algorithms for cylinder-something intersection assume that the cylinder is infinite length. For finite cylinders, there's a post processing step where you check if intersection is between the ends.

Comment: @Ouroborus I was able to make the infinite cylinder check work (ended up being pretty easy as soon as you said squash the mesh into the plane), HOWEVER... one of the effects I wanted from this was to know if the cylinder is COMPLETELY blocked-- that's not even possible is it?  It's like I'd need to move each individual triangle TOWARD the axis by the radius of the cylinder, so no way to do that without it being a workhorse, correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's a lot harder. I don't have any fancy way to do that. A way to approximate that is, after flattening everything, test evenly distributed points within the circle to see if they're inside any of the triangles. If you find one that isn't you have a hole that aligns (or are outside the mesh). The accuracy depends on how dense the points are but can never be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things become easier when the axis are coincident with the objects.

Translate main axis to any point in the axis-line you have.

Rotate main axis so the Z-axis is axis of your cylinder. I think the typical "LookAt" function used in OpenGL does both translation & rotation in one matrix.

Now you can scale the objects.

Rotate back, translate back, in this order. Or use the inverse of the LookAt matrix.

If you need cylinder-triangle collision I recomend the same method. Once you have things in the axis-line system you only need X,Y coordinates, so you have a 2D circle-triangle intersection, which is much easier than the 3D problem.